# Text editor or a standalone tool for Mac OS with ability to compress JavaScript code

Tags: macos, code-editor

Here is the task: I would like my JavaScript code from different files to be compressed and concatenated into one file that is going to be used on a web page. The problem is that I'm pretty lazy :) and using some command line tools like, for instance, Apache Ant + YUICompressor each time I add a new line of code doesn't look attractive too me. Replacing uncompressed versions with a compressed final script before release is not a great option as well.

I know that such IDE as Eclipse allow to build project automatically after each update so it is possible to use already mentioned Apache Ant and YUICompressor in a build scenario to reach my goal. However Eclipse is too geeky for me, it's not that I can't figure out how to use it, I just don't feel comfortable using it. Maybe someone knows a good alternative (for Mac OS)?

PS. I hope I don't sound too capricious :) , after all having convenient tools is rather important for a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a bundle for TextMate called JavaScript Tools that contain two built-in text compressors, available at http://andrewdupont.net/2006/10/01/javascript-tools-textmate-bundle/ .  TextMate is available at http://macromates.com/ .

Comment: Thanks! I'll surely try it. I wonder if there is something like that for Komodo IDE. This is my favourite development tool so far.